# Drag image into CKEditor 4 (NO upload)

Tags: ckeditor4.x

I'd like to have an image or div that I can drag and drop into the CKEditor 4. How can I achieve this?

My DOMElement has the full path to the image - pretend it is an  with a src attribute. The image has alredy been uploaded to the server, so all I want to do is get the URL of the image being dragged into the CKEditor and insert an image tag with the scr set.

I am listening to both drop and paste events, but my data is always empty...

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function (e) {
        e.editor.on('paste', function (event) {

            event.stop();

            var data = event.data.dataValue;

            if (window.chrome || window.safari) {
                // removing span wrapper on webkit browsers.
                data = $(data).html();
            }

            //This is always empty...
            console.log(event.editor.getData());

            event.editor.insertHtml(data);

        });

        e.editor.on('drop', function (ev) {
            console.log("drop", ev);
        });

    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so it turns out that:

```
$('.foo').draggable({
    helper: "clone"
});
```

is the answer, but if it doesn't work at first, try put the `overflow:auto`; on another element.